# Custom XPath Sonar rule for Java unit test

Tags: java, xpath, junit, sonarqube

We had a case of someone using the `JUnit 3` style approach of extending `TestCase` but not calling the class `Test` which meant it didn't get picked up and run by Jenkins.

Here's the *XPath* expression I tried to register but unfortunately Sonar isn't catching violations:

`//classDeclaration[IDENTIFIER[not(ends-with(@tokenValue,'Test'))]`

and

```
 classType[@tokenValue="TestCase"]]
```

I've copied the current *XPath* template in Sonar 3.6.

Is it possible to catch a custom `Sonar` violation/issue with Java test classes?

Answer (score 0):

No. XPath rules can currently apply on source code only (not unit test code).
Feel free to follow and vote for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3748